# Sending raw JSON using Postman value is null

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

A pleasant day.

I am having trouble with simply displaying string in raw JSON format using Postman.

This is what I have in my Java code:

```
 @RestController
public class HeroController {

    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST}, value = "/displayHero")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> displayInfo(String name){
        //System.out.println(name);
        Map<String, String> imap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("hero", name);
        return imap;
    }

}
```

Every time I test this in Postman, I always get ***null*** (again if I am using raw format):

```
{
    "hero": null
}
```

But using *form-data*, on the other hand, displays just what I entered.

```
{
"hero": "wolverine"
}
```

Any information, or should do in Postman to make this raw format works instead of form-data?  By the way, the raw format value is **JSON(application/json)**, and in the Header Tab, the value of Content-Type is **application/json; charset=UTF-8**.

Thank you and have a nice day ahead.

Comment: to support the raw json format as input from request, you will need to make changes on server end. On server end, you will have to update the logic to consume the request body as json, according to whichever framework you are using.

Comment: Thank you @nandal for the insight.  I am using Tomcat and using Spring Boot as my framework.  Should I mention Gradle too as an additional framework?  My sincere apologies, it's really somewhat my first time to work on SpringBoot, Gradle and Postman.  Is there any article I could read where I could follow these step by step?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for consuming the request body as JSON, in spring boot:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/displayHero", method = POST, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String displayInfo(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) {
    String json = httpEntity.getBody();
    // json contains the plain json string
    // now you can process the json object information as per your need
    // and return output as per requirements.
    return json;
}
```

This code will accept json body of POST Request and then return it as response.

Comment: Thank you @nandal.  It works now.  But should I still use the object json to get the data I input from the fields?  My task is to input using raw-format JSON and to get the value from a field.  In my example, I should get the "wolverine" data and store that data (together with other fields) in the database.  There are two more fields to enter, "skills" and "team", again, whatever data I will put on this field, I could get it and store in in a database. Thank you for your kindest considerations.

Comment: Hi @Marky, using JSON format is more RESTful, If the API is supposed to be consumed by different platforms and utilities. But if it is only has to be consumed by HTML Forms, then you can use form-data. But if it has to be consumed as input from AJAX and other frameworks, then data should be handled as JSON.

Comment: Hello @nandal, my sincere apologies for not replying back. Nevertheless, I got it working now. Thank you so my for the head start (specif. using HttpEntity). Another knowledge acquired. Have a blessed day to you and to all.